# How to iterate over an array and check element type at the same time in swift?

Tags: swift, loops, syntax

I'd like to know if it is possible to iterate over an array is swift and check if the current element has a certain type.
A use case would be : I have an array with `NSDictionary`s and `NSArray`s and I ony want to take care of the `NSDictionary`s.

I'd like to do this without the condition inside the loop :

```
for entity in array
{
    if entity is NSDictionary
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

I'm looking for something like :

```
for (entity in array) as? NSDictionary
{
    // Do something
}
```

Of course I know that what I have just written doesn't work, but I guess you can get the idea of what I'm asking for.

Any idea would be really appreciated !

Comment: In your case it would be `for case let entity as NSDictionary in array { ... }`, which enumerates exactly the elements of type NSDictionary in the array, without creating an intermediate filtered array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution 1

You can filter your array

```
let things = [NSDictionary(), NSArray(), NSDictionary(), NSArray()]

let dicts = things.flatMap { $0 as? NSDictionary }
```

Now `dicts` is defined as `[NSDictionary]` an contains only the 2 dictionaries.

### Solution 2

You can also perform a for loop only on the values that are dictionaries

```
let things = [NSDictionary(), NSArray(), NSDictionary(), NSArray()]

for dict in things.flatMap( { $0 as? NSDictionary }) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the second solution is exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov: Hi Alexander, the problem is that you cannot use the trailing closure syntax inside an IF condition without wrapping the whole condition into a `( ... )`

Comment: @appzYourLife Oh you're right! I suppose that makes sense. I think the compiler could be made to work without it, but it probably wouldn't be the worth the work

Answer (score 2):

#### Using `filter` with the type check operator `is`

As an alternative to the `flatMap` solutions, you may use `filter` along with the type check operator `is`:

```
let arr: [AnyObject] = [NSDictionary(), ["foo", "bar"], NSDictionary(), "foo"]

for dict in arr.filter({ $0 is NSDictionary }) {
    // do something with dictionary
}
```

> Use the type check operator (`is`) to check whether an instance is of
>   a certain subclass type. The type check operator returns `true` if the
>   instance is of that subclass type and `false` if it is not.

From [Swift Language Guide - Type Casting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html). Since you don't have to worry about subclass matches (you know the elements to be either `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`) the `is` filter approach can be an appropriate alternative here.

Note that when using the `flatMap` and type cast operator (`as`), the iterate element in the `for` loop (`dict`) will be of type `NSDictionary`, whereas the `filter` approach above will perform no downcasting, hence preserving the `NSDictionary` in its wrapped form, as `AnyObject`. Probably the `flatMap` approach is to prefer here.

Comment: Thanks, it works as well

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care for elements to have the same indexes as in original array, you can `flatMap` to the required type.

```
for element in array.flatMap({ $0 as? NSDictionary }) {
    // do something 
}
```